# Match lines that do not contain a word using java regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to match all in lines that do not contain the word "you".

Example :

```
you are smart                 
i and you not same            
This is not my fault          
Which one is yours
```

Result :

```
This is not m fault
Which one i yours             <-- this is match because the word is "yours"
```

I tried using `\\b(?!you)\\w+`, but it's only ignoring the word "you".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use word boundaries and starting anchor.

```
"^(?!.*\\byou\\b).*"
```

`(?!.*\\byou\\b)` negative lookahead at start asserts that the string `you` surrounded by word boundaries won't be  present at anywhere in the line. If yes, `.*` then match all the characters in that corresponding line. NOte that the `.*` inside the negative lookahead is very important or otherwise, it would check only at the start. `^` Asserts that we are at the start and `\b` called word boundary which matches between a word character and a non-word character.

```
String s[] = {"you are smart", "i and you not same", "This is not my fault", "Which one is yours"};
for(String i : s)
{
 System.out.println(i.matches("^(?!.*\\byou\\b).*"));
}
```

**Output:**

```
false
false
true
true
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wX9fR1/1)

OR

To match all the words except `you`

```
"(?!\\byou\\b)\\b\\w+\\b"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wX9fR1/2)

```
String s = "you are smart\n" + 
        "i and you not same\n" + 
        "This is not my fault\n" + 
        "Which one is yours";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?m)^(?!.*\\byou\\b).*").matcher(s);
while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

**Output:**

```
This is not my fault
Which one is yours
```

Comment: it is in one of String, but not in one lines.

Comment: @newbie see my update. It's hard to predict your needs . Please update your question with expected output.

Comment: I deleted my answer and (`+1`) you, I don't think OP knows what he/she wants.

Comment: your regex just ignore word "you" only, not all in one line.

Comment: @newbie OMG, i don't know what you mean.. Explain your question more clearly.

Comment: i have update my post, i hope you can solve my problem.
sorry for my english

Comment: @newbie that's what the first regex does. It matches the whole line where the string `\byou\b` is not present. Your English confuses me a lot....

Answer (score 0):

modify your pattern to

```
\\b(?!you\\b)\\w+
```

adding a word boundary after `you`